# Google plus integration using social auth library in android

Tags: android, authentication, google-plus

I have successfully integrated facebook,twitter using social auth,
But i am getting issue while integrating google plus integration.I can login but unable to share anything.

Error :- 
org.brickred.socialauth.exception.SocialAuthException: java.io.FileNotFoundException: https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token

If anyone have idea please reply.

Thanks in advance....

I am using the below code :-

**Authenticating :-**

```
SocialAuthAdapter googlePlusAdapter;

    try
            {
                            googlePlusAdapter = new SocialAuthAdapter(new ResponseListener());
                            googlePlusAdapter.addCallBack(Provider.GOOGLEPLUS, "http://localhost");
                            googlePlusAdapter.authorize(this,org.brickred.socialauth.android.SocialAuthAdapter.Provider.GOOGLEPLUS);
            } catch (Exception e) {

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Exception " + e.toString(), 1).show();
           }
```

**Sharing :-**

```
        try{

             String msg="post from my app"; 

        googlePlusAdapter.updateStatus(msg, new SocialAuthListener<Integer>() {

            @Override
            public void onExecute(String arg0, Integer t) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Integer status = t;
                if (status.intValue() == 200 || status.intValue() == 201 ||status.intValue() == 204)
                {    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message posted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                     googlePlusAdapter.signOut(Provider.GOOGLEPLUS.toString()); 
                }
                else
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message not posted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onError(SocialAuthError error) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Message not posted!! Try again",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }, true);

        finish();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }
```

Comment: Did you were able to solve this? I have the same problem. I think the problem is the line: googlePlusAdapter.addCallBack(Provider.GOOGLEPLUS, "http://localhost"); But if yo comment that line you will get a redirect_uri_mismatch, and I could not find a way to modify that field in my google app(https://cloud.google.com/console/project).

Comment: No,I was done without social auth. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16461345/google-plus-sharing-from-android-app/20300395#20300395

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have created a Client ID for Android application. 
You have to create a Client ID for web application, then in that option you have to assing a redirect_uri.

Steps:

1. Go to https://cloud.google.com/console/project
2. Select your project
3. Select APIs & auth, then Credentials
4. Press Crate new Client ID
5. Create a Web application type.
6. Put a valid uri that can respond to YOUR_URL/oauth2callback

So in your code:

```
googlePlusAdapter.addCallBack(Provider.GOOGLEPLUS, "http://localhost");
```

You have to write like this:

```
googlePlusAdapter.addCallBack(Provider.GOOGLEPLUS, same_uri_you_put_in_redirect_uri);
```

This is because socialauth authenticate through http.

Comment: do we have to put something actually at YOUR_URL/oauth2callback ?