# Google-plus integration in android: ERROR: "An internal error occurred"

Tags: android, google-plus, google-play-services

After login and verifying the password, the app forcefully terminates by toasting 'An internal error occurred' ! I am following the code of this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16461345/google-plus-sharing-from-android-app/20300395#20300395).
I am trying to post a text, so anything else should i add in my code,i dont know how?

Logcat: `01-19 01:05:01.304: E/ShareActivity(1358): Unable to sign the user in.`

I have also registered my app on google api console. I know that similar kind of questions exists here but all of their answers are telling about the CLIENT_ID. My CLIENT_ID is absolutely perfect!

How can this issue be solved?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Are you 100% confident of your client ID - e.g. make sure the signing key that is specified there is definitely the key used in the app on the device. Sometimes people have been using a different debug keystore than they thought, and hence set the wrong signature in the API console.

If that's all good, try running the application with more verbose logging:

```
adb shell setprop log.tag.GooglePlusPlatform VERBOSE
```

See if that gives you any more information that may help indicate what the problem is.

You can also try clearing the local Google Play Services cache. If you go to the Google Settings app, in the overflow menu there is a "clear app data" option. That might help if it was an older issue which was cached locally.

Comment: I tried changing my CLIENT_ID 3-4 times usng SHA1,packageName,etc..!
 but my app is not using that CLIENT_ID. Is it necessary to use?How?
And how can i use this functionality [adb shell setprop log.tag.GooglePlusPlatform VERBOSE](https://developers.google.com/+/mobile/android/getting-started#frequently_asked_questions)